# malloc does not guarantee returning physically contiguous memory

Tags: memory-management, malloc

I'm reading about virtual memory and my conclusions are the following:

```
malloc(size);
```

1. malloc does not guarantee to return physically contiguous memory. It guarantees to return virtually contiguous memory. Especially it is true when size > 4KB because 4KB is the size of page. (On Linux systems).

Am I right or am I wrong? Please explain.

Comment: More or less right, but (a) the page size is not necessarily 4 kB, and (b) even a small allocation (< 1 VM page) may span more than one VM page, since it can start more or less anywhere within a page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> malloc does not guarantee returning physically contiguous memory

yes

> It guarantees returning virtually contiguous memory

yes

> Especially it is true when size > 4KB because 4KB is a size of page.
>   ( On Linux systems).

Being contiguous memory does not imply that it will also be page aligned. The allcated memory can start from any address in heap. So whatever OS uses the page size it does not affect the allocation nature of malloc.

Comment: when it comes to stack, the situation is analogous?

Comment: I think you can not map on stack by yourself. Assigning memory to stack is automatic, initially size set by compiler. I never see any system call which affect stack growth in up/downward.

Comment: check this link (accepted answer) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux

Comment: @Gilgamesz : if you really want to allocate from the stack, check out `alloca` - it's a nonstandard (not in C, not even in POSIX) function that allocates some space in the current function's stack frame. However, it will also be only virtually contiguous. I'm not an expert on the kernel, but what you want (for whatever reason) is surely possible by writing a custom kernel module. Or you could poke around `mmap`, which can perhaps be persuaded into mapping some physically contiguous memory into your process.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar you are right about alloca. I came to know about alloca a few days ago. But still I will not recommend to design solution which needs alloca due to security concerns.

Comment: what do you mean when answering to a negative question "yes"? Do you mean "yes, it does", or "yes, you are correct"?

Answer (score 2):

malloc just allocate memory from heap , in a virtual memory system complete  allocate memory to a process different section (text , data , bss ,heap , stack) is virtually contiguous. Every section of process allocated a virtual memory region by using mmap.

in case of extension of heap it is basically allocated a virtual memory region allocated by brk() system call. it is not affected if size is greater the 4kb.
though linux has concept of HUGETLB page to avoid frequent TLB misses, but that is internal to Linux.